# How can I find the row & column in a JSON String identified by a JsonPath?

Tags: json, jsonpath

Suppose I have a JSON string like this example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane"
  }
]
```

Using JSONPath I want to select the second name like this:

```
[1].name
```

However, I am not interested in the name's value but rather in the row & column of the entire second name key-value pair as they appear in the String. In this example, the expected result when written as a JSON would be:

```
{
  "row": 5,
  "column": 4
}
```

Alternatively, the index within the String would be fine as well. Note that I don't require the result to be a JSON. Note also that this should work with any formatting of the JSON.

I have thought about constructing a regular expression but this might be fragile if the key's name *"name"* also appears as text in values.

I am using Jayway JSONPath in my Java backend but a solution with a different JSONPath library, or one in JavaScript using an Node.js compatible library would also be fine.

Comment: What is your expected result as json?

Comment: I have edited the question to make this more clear

Comment: Which row and column do you mean? Do you want to treat the JSON as a document where whitespace matters?

Comment: The row and column of the start of the second "name" instance within the JSON string. The row and column thus depend on the whitespace within the JSON string/document. Does that make my question more clear? If so, I will edit it.